# How to create a downloadable URL for a file placed in unix server?

Tags: file, unix, url, download

I have a requirement where I need to create a downloadable URL for a file placed in the unix server and mail the link to multiple users.

I tried using :- http://${server}:${port}/${filepath}/${filename} - but the link is not working... Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to serve a file via `http` you need to setup an http server like Apache to do that.

Maybe this [digitalocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps) will help you to do that.

Comment: So it seems I have to install apache2 and configure http. Thanks a lot. :-)